# Center text for a title and subtitle

Tags: android

I need to place a title and subtitle in this way:

```
 |----------App Name and Version----------|
 |--------------------My Company----------|
```

I'm confused, I just can't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is easily achievable by using `RelativeLayout`.

You can specify `alignEnd` attribute on the second `TextView` and pass the id of the first `TextView`. Also, you will have to specify `layoutBelow` attribute and pass in again the id of the first `TextView`.

Also, if the first `TextView` is centered horizontally, you can set `centerHorizontal` attribute to true.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text_view_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_1"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think he meant he want the second text to start in the center of the first text. In your solution, it will be only aligned to the end of the first text.

Comment: Yes, in case it is the way you are suggesting then my solution won't work. But he hasn't clarified anything. let's see. :)

Comment: I need align on the end of the 1st text view im worknig in this now

Comment: I use eclipse, and when i try your answer @SarthakMittal eclipse say:
"No resource identifier found for atribute 'layout_alignEnd' in package Android"

Comment: @fbwnd your answer is very inspirating to... tkns

Comment: @AgustinLoCastro add this: android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text_view_1"

Comment: tkns you very! @SarthakMittal

Comment: @AgustinLoCastro anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Apparently I didn't understand the question. The answer below will help you align the second text to start in the center of the first.

You should use RelativeLayout.

You can try something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        .../>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadowView"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/shadowView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_1"
        .../>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In case you support older version than API 17, use toRightOf instead of toEndOf